# Is there any solution to update Drawer in react-native-router-flux from another components

Tags: react-native, drawer, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to create a dynamic drawer in react-native-router-flux.
I Mean when I changed the Scenes drawer can detect which scene in now activated and can update itself by new data.
I have a Component in my drawer that calls in App.js

```
<Drawer
    key={'drawer'}
    contentComponent = {() => <DrawerLayout language={this.state.language} />}
    drawerPosition= {this.state.rightOrLeft}

    <Stack key={'root'} hideNavBar>
        <Scene key={'splash'} component={Splash} initial/>
        <Scene key={'login'} component={Login} />
        <Scene key={'home'} component={Home} />
        <Scene key={'about'} component={About} />
    </Stack>
</Drawer>
```

I wish I could explain my dream correctly !!!

Comment: For future reference : Finally I reached the goal by using Redux.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using redux you can retain state and fetch the current scene from store and play around with it.

If you are not using redux, you can still get to do it without it. One option is to do the following:

1. use contentComponent in DrawerNavigator and fetch the content from a separate js file.

   `contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />`
2. Now you need global variable declare in App.js name as currentScene and set your home page as default.
3. Now lets join all in sideBar.js, on click of every menu item change the global variable value to the selected menu.
4. Based on the value of current scene in SideBar.js change menuItems List.

One good example is react native base kitchen sink example app. Read the code in it follow the four steps once you are familiarise with it and  you will be done.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink

Comment: Many thanks dear friend, the only problem is That I can't detect when the global variable is changed in my drawer, is there any solution instead of Redux or using setInterval in componentDidMount()

Comment: You don't need any change event you can save it in the state variable it will manage it. You can also store value of current screen in asyncStorage or if you are using realm, can store in realm object, though it is not best practice. If you use redux instead that would be better. @AliEsfandiari

Comment: Finally I reached the goal by using redux, it was really complicated at the beginning, thanks friend.

Comment: Mark the answer correct if it helped. Also, if you can upload the redux learning project and share the link it would be helpful for others.